# Unread message count is broken in the title of the Inbox tab

Tags: bug, ios-app

Title of the Inbox page says that I have 2 unread messages, but all messages are read (moreover there is no red count indicator on the tab icon):

> [image: 2 unread]

- App Version: 1.6.2.5
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.2 (Build 14C92)